# MPI_BARRIER not working

Tags: c, mpi, barrier

Why is here the barrier not working? If I use it, the program gets blocked, otherwise I get the output in a weird order:

```
Number of worker tasks = 4
   sending 1-th element q=0.011000 to task 1
   sending 2-th element q=0.012000 to task 2
   received 1-th element q=0.011000 in task 1
   processed 1-th element q=6.105000 in task 1
   sending 3-th element q=0.013000 to task 3
   received 2-th element q=0.012000 in task 2
   processed 2-th element q=13.320000 in task 2
   sending 4-th element q=0.014000 to task 4
   received 3-th element q=0.013000 in task 3
   processed 3-th element q=21.645000 in task 3
 starting to get data in MASTER
   MASTER received 0-th element q=6.105000 from task 1
   MASTER received 0-th element q=13.320000 from task 2
   received 4-th element q=0.014000 in task 4
   processed 4-th element q=31.080000 in task 4
   MASTER received 0-th element q=21.645000 from task 3
   MASTER received 0-th element q=31.080000 from task 4
 end
```

Code:

```
#include "mpi.h"               /* required MPI library */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NRRR 16               /* number of rows in matrix A */
#define NLLL 16                 /* number of columns in matrix A */
#define MASTER 0               /* taskid of first task */
#define FROM_MASTER 1          /* setting a message type */
#define FROM_WORKER 2          /* setting a message type */

int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int numtasks,              /* number of tasks in partition */
    taskid,                /* a task identifier */
    numworkers,            /* number of worker tasks */
    source,                /* task id of message source */
    dest,                  /* task id of message destination */
    mtype,
    i,j,
    rc;                 /* message type */
    double  qr[NRRR],
    ql[NLLL],
    element_r[NRRR][3],
    element_l[NLLL][3];           


    MPI_Status status;  
    rc = MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    rc|= MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);   
    rc|= MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid); 

    if (rc != 0)
        printf ("error initializing MPI and obtaining task ID info\n");

    numworkers = numtasks-1;

    // MASTER
    if (taskid == MASTER)
    {
        printf("\n\n\n\nNumber of worker tasks = %d\n",numworkers);

        // init element_r and element_l
        for(j=0;j<NRRR;j++){
            element_r[j][0]=j;
            element_r[j][1]=j+1;
            element_r[j][2]=j+2;
            qr[j] = j*1e-4+1e-3;
        }

        for(i=0;i<NLLL;i++){
            element_l[i][0]=12000+i;
            element_l[i][1]=12000+i+1;
            element_l[i][2]=12000+i+2;
            ql[i] = i*1e-3 +1e-2 ;
        }

        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++)
        {
            printf("   sending %d-th element q=%f to task %d\n",dest,ql[dest],dest);
            MPI_Send(&ql[dest], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);                        
        }


        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        printf(" starting to get data in MASTER\n");
        for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++)
        {
            source = i;
            MPI_Recv(&ql[source], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        } 
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++)
        {
            source = i;
            printf("   MASTER received %d-th element q=%f from task %d\n",taskid,ql[source],source);            
        } 
        printf(" end\n");

    }

    // WORKER
    if (taskid > MASTER)
    {
        mtype = FROM_MASTER;        
        MPI_Recv(&ql, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("   received %d-th element q=%f in task %d\n",taskid,ql[0],taskid);
        ql[0]=ql[0]*555*taskid;
        printf("   processed %d-th element q=%f in task %d\n",taskid,ql[0],taskid);

        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        MPI_Send(&ql, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MPI_Barrier](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node95.html#SECTION00540000000000000000) is a collective communication call: it will block until all processes in the communicator that was supplied in the parameter called it. Since your worker processes never call MPI_Barrier, the master blocks indefinitely.

Comment: Ok, then I added MPI_BARRIER at the end of woker tasks and now everything seems to work ok. Now I wonder if I get performance penalty when using barrier

Comment: There are some performance penalties when using barriers, but they are a necessary evil if you need to synchronise your processes in order to get correct behaviour. One aspect of optimising parallel algorithms is to design your code such that synchronisation is not required.

Comment: @Werner: Well, it is true that Barrier can only hurt performance, never improve it. On the other hand, it can make things more convenient for you as a developer. At other times, processes may not be able to perform anything meaningful until other processes finish certain tasks, so a Barrier is indispensible. It's up to you to assess whether a Barrier is required, or the performance loss is tolerated.

Comment: Can you please take a look in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247968/mpi-barrier-throws-error-while-run-the-code    Thank you.