# How does MPI_Barrier() work?

Tags: mpi

I have this code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0)
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    cout << "Some output\n";
    if (rank == 1)
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    cout << "end\n";
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run as

> mpiexec -n 2 MPI.exe

the program works; the output is:

```
Some output
End
Some output
End
```

However, when I run as

> mpiexec -n 3 MPI.exe

the program does *not* work properly. I expected for output like this:

```
rank 3 - Some_output
rank 2 - Some output
rank 3 - End
rank 0 - Some output
```

At this step, I expect the program to stop.

Comment: Please reformat output into and indented block so that it is more readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898075/mpi-barrier-not-working

Comment: Fixed output formatting; corrected grammar and word choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure then number of Barrier calls is the same for each process.  In your particular case, when n=3 you have two Barrier calls for rank 0 and rank 1 but only 1 for rank 2.  The program will block until the rank 2 process also reaches a Barrier.

Here is what should be happening for n=3:

```
together:
    rank 0 will reach barrier 1 then block
    rank 1 will print "some output", reach barrier 2 then block
    rank 2 will print "some output", reach barrier 3 then block
together:
    rank 0 will print "some output", reach barrier 3 then block
    rank 1 will reach barrier 3 then block
    rank 2 will print "end" then hit finalize
```

Having one process in finalize while others are blocked is going to be undefined behaviour.

---

Doing the same analysis for n=2:

```
together:
    rank 0 will reach barrier 1 then block
    rank 1 will print "some output", reach barrier 2 then block
together:
    rank 0 will print "some output", reach barrier 3 then block
    rank 1 will reach barrier 3 then block
together:
    rank 0 will print "end" then hit finalize
    rank 1 will print "end" then hit finalize
```

This suggests the output should be:

```
some output
some output
end 
end
```

however you are getting:

```
some output
end 
some output
end
```

This has to do with how the mpi infrastructure is caching the transfer of stdout from the various ranks.  We can see the behaviour better if we introduce a delay so that MPI decides it should gather the results:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0) {
        cout << rank << " Barrier 1\n" << flush;
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    cout << rank << " Some output \n" << flush;
    usleep(1000000);
    if (rank == 1) {
        cout << rank << " Barrier 2\n" << flush;
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    cout << rank << " Barrier 3\n" << flush;
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    cout << rank << " end\n" << flush;
    usleep(1000000);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

which produces:

```
$ mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out 
0 Barrier 1
1 Some output 
0 Some output 
1 Barrier 2
1 Barrier 3
0 Barrier 3
0 end
1 end

$ mpiexec -n 3 ./a.out 
2 Some output 
0 Barrier 1
1 Some output 
0 Some output 
1 Barrier 2
1 Barrier 3
2 Barrier 3
2 end
0 Barrier 3
^Cmpiexec: killing job...
```

Alternatively, look at the time stamps from the following C++11 code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline unsigned long int time(void) { 
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count(); 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0) {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    cout << rank << " " << time() << " Some output\n";
    if (rank == 1) {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    cout << rank << " " << time() << " end\n";
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
$ mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out 
0 1464100768220965374 Some output
0 1464100768221002105 end
1 1464100768220902046 Some output
1 1464100768221000693 end
```

sorted by timestamp:

```
$ mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out 
1 1464100768220902046 Some output
0 1464100768220965374 Some output
1 1464100768221000693 end
0 1464100768221002105 end
```

The conclusion is that Barrier is behaving as expected, and that print statements are not necessarily going to tell you that.

Edit: 2016-05-24 to show detailed analysis of program behaviour.

Comment: The program will block, but why I haven't output from rank 3? I expect that rank 3 will print "Some output", but is didn't happened.

Comment: @van9petryk, I added a more detailed analysis.  For my particular setup, it does capture the output from rank 2 before I hit Ctrl-C to kill the program.  If your mpi fails immediately when rank 2 is at finalize and the other ranks are at barrier, it may not bother to gather the rank 2 stdout.